# Floating loop in a sketchup plugin

Tags: ruby, sketchup

I need to loop on a floating point but I don't find the right syntax.
What I tried:

```
(-1.0).upto(1.0).step(0.1) do |t|
    ...
end
```

I get the following error:

> Error: #NoMethodError: undefined method `upto' for -1.0:Float>

**EDIT**: Is there a "good" or better way to do this loop?

Comment: It is not a good idea at all, but this will work (except you should round your floating points):
`(-1.0..1.0).step(0.1).to_a.each { |e| e }`

Comment: @yzalavin Why wouln't it be a good idea? Is there a "good" way to do it?

Comment: May the downvote explain their reasons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use step on a `Range`:

```
(-1.0..1.0).step(0.1) { |i|
  puts i
}
```

Note, while you increment with 0.1 you will run into floating point precision issue. So take that into consideration.

```
-1.0
-0.9
-0.8
-0.7
-0.6
-0.5
-0.39999999999999997
-0.29999999999999993
-0.19999999999999996
-0.09999999999999995
5.551115123125783e-17
0.10000000000000006
0.20000000000000007
0.30000000000000004
0.4000000000000001
0.5000000000000001
0.6000000000000001
0.7000000000000001
0.8
0.9000000000000001
1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `#upto` method for Float but you can create your own similar method

```
class Float
  def upto(target, options={})
    options = {step: 1.0}.merge(options)
    current_value = self
    while current_value < target
      yield current_value
      current_value += options[:step]
    end
  end
end
```

You can then do...

```
(-1.0).upto(1.0, step: 0.1) do |t|
    ...
end
```

Comment: Since the question being in context of SketchUp, indicating he's producing an extension, it's worth noting that extensions hosted on the SketchUp Extension Warehouse are not allowed to modify Ruby API namespace in order to avoid clashes. Instead it would have to take the float as an argument.